# Definitions of VaR (Value at Risk)

Tags: quantiles, bounds, risk

Here is the definition of VaR (Value at Risk) taken from McNeil, Alexander J., Rüdiger Frey and Paul Embrechts (2015), *Quantitative risk
management: Concepts, techniques and tools*:
$$
\textrm{VaR}_{\alpha}(L)=\inf\{l\in\mathbb{R}\colon P(L>l)\leq 1-\alpha\}
 =\inf\{l\in\mathbb{R}\colon F_{L}(l)\geq\alpha\}
$$
where $L$ is the Loss distribution and $F_L$ its cumulative distribution function.

I would like to translate it in terms of Profit & Loss distribution $X=-L$ but I'm a bit unsure this is correct:
$$\textrm{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)=-\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R}\colon P(X<x)\leq 1-\alpha\}$$
$$
= -\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R}\colon F_{X}(x)\geq 1-\alpha\}$$

Obviously, the two values must be the same, that is:

$$\textrm{VaR}_{\alpha}(L)=\textrm{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)=\textrm{VaR}_{\alpha}$$

Could you please check my formula?
In particular, should I use $\sup$ instead of $\inf$?

Answer (score 0):

I drew some graphs, and now I think I can answer my own question.

$$\textrm{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)=-\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R}\colon P(X<x)\leq 1-\alpha\}$$

is *wrong* because I have to take the upper bound, since the set is made of negative numbers, so 
$$\textrm{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)=-\sup\{x\in\mathbb{R}\colon P(X<x)\leq 1-\alpha\}$$
is the correct formula.

$$\textrm{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)= -\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R}\colon F_{X}(x)\geq 1-\alpha\}$$
is correct, but to make it equivalent to the formula with the Loss distribution, even when there is no minimum, it should be:
$$\textrm{VaR}_{\alpha}(X)= -\sup\{x\in\mathbb{R}\colon F_{X}(x)\leq 1-\alpha\}$$